# Segfault in C from printf, no warning

Tags: c

Here is a short simple program which segfaults when run. It gives no warnings on clang, even at pedantic level.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct object {
    int type;
} object;

void write(object *obj) {
    switch (obj->type) {
    case 1:
        break;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    printf("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

The crash doesn't seem to happen on x86 Linux, but I'm on aarch64 Android.

```
$ gcc --version
clang version 17.0.6
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-android24
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin

$ uname -a
Linux localhost 5.10.177-android13-4-00003-ga7208022a7ea-ab10815828 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Sep 15 16:40:54 UTC 2023 aarch64 Android
```

Tracing it with gdb makes it seem like `printf` ends up calling `write`, but I've no idea now that could come about.

This looks like a compiler bug, but I can compile and run other programs fine. If I remove the `printf` from `main` or the definition of `write` then this runs as expected. Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 5):

`write` is the name of a library function.  Creating a function with this name can override the library function and result in it getting called instead.  The implementation of `printf` most likely uses `write`.

Definition functions or variables with the same name as reserved library functions can trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code, so change the name to something else.

Comment: This is a defect in the C implementation. `write` is not a reserved name in the C standard. Programs ought to be able to use it.

Comment: The program only does `printf("hi");` so anything else is likely to be optimised out.

Comment: @WeatherVane It can't optimize out a function with external linkage, since it might be called from another compilation unit. And in fact, that's what's happening here, it's being called from stdio.

Comment: @Barmar: Pedantically, if the compiler is compiling for a hosted implementation, it can determine there is no way to call `write` during program execution, since `main` does not call it. The fact that `printf` might call it would be irrelevant to that, as `printf` in a hosted implementation must work on its own (with the standard library), not by calling user routines named `write`.

Comment: @Barmar how can that happen? The `stdio` function will reference `io.h` or wherever but this code does not. C does not have overloading.

Comment: I'll bet there's a compiler or linker option that will make this work, but it's not the default. The allows you to use things like `LD_PRELOAD` to override system calls like `write()`. I'm having trouble finding a google search to find the option.

Comment: @WeatherVane I assume `printf(3)` calls `write(2)` from `unistd.h`. Ideally it would call it through an alternate name prefixed with `_` so it's reserved to the implementation. But it calls it through the standard name to allow overriding.

Comment: @Barmar but the *compiler* doesn't know that `write` is used by `printf` when it compiles this module. It isn't even used here.

Comment: @WeatherVane The problem isn't the compiler, it's stdio. It needs to call sonmething like `__internal_write` rather than `write` so it won't be broken by a user-defined write. I suspect it's controlled by a macro that you can provide in the compilation line.

Comment: As @Barmar says, printf is calling `write` (indirectly) and presumably expecting the one from `unistd.h` but getting my one. Am I crazy, or is this a bug? I didn't include that header and I shouldn't have to worry about its declarations.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's by design. This is how you can override the system call to make `printf()` use your own definition of `write()`, as when mocking during unit tests. There's almost certainly a way to prevent it with an appropriate `-D` option during compiling, I just don't know what it is.

Comment: dbush, "Definition functions or variables with the same name as reserved library functions can trigger undefined behavior in your code" is true, yet asserting `write()` is _reserved_ is unsupported.  Please provide a cite.